# If then depending on change in value in lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to read out 5 microswitches and calculate how many are active and which ones. In this, I've succeeded. However, I'd also like to know how many are taken while a door is opened (`doorstatus == 0` means it's opened). Is there a way to detect the change in doorstatus other than using `while doorstatus == 1 do`? For example: an if then loop that detects a change in doorstatus from 0 to 1

My code right now (which doesn't work):

```
if global.doorstatus == 1 then -- door closed
    checkMicroswitches() -- checks the microswitches
    calculateFree() -- calculates the amount and place of free microswitches
    global.numberFreeStart = global.numberFree
    global.rfidTakenCheck = 0
end

msg.payload = global.numberFreeStart
msg.topic = "numberFreeStart"
sendTo(4, msg)

while (global.doorstatus == 0) do -- door open, rfidTakenCheck = total taken while door was open
    checkMicroswitches()
    calculateFree()
    global.numberFreeEnd = global.numberFree
    global.rfidTakenCheck = global.numberFreeStart - global.numberFreeEnd
    msg.payload = {}
    msg.payload = global.rfidTakenCheck
    msg.topic = "rfidTakenCheck"
    sendTo(3, msg)
    if global.doorstatus == 1 then
        break
    end
end
```

The program gets stuck because of the while loop, so I'd like to change that. I don't know how, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code to something like this:

```
local function doorClosed() -- door closed
    checkMicroswitches() -- checks the microswitches
    calculateFree() -- calculates the amount and place of free microswitches
    global.numberFreeStart = global.numberFree
    global.rfidTakenCheck = 0
end

local function doorOpen() -- door open, rfidTakenCheck = total taken while door was open
    checkMicroswitches()
    calculateFree()
    global.numberFreeEnd = global.numberFree
    global.rfidTakenCheck = global.numberFreeStart - global.numberFreeEnd
    msg.payload = {}
    msg.payload = global.rfidTakenCheck
    msg.topic = "rfidTakenCheck"
    sendTo(3, msg)
end

msg.payload = global.numberFreeStart
msg.topic = "numberFreeStart"
sendTo(4, msg)

while(true) do
    global.doorstatus == updateDoorStatus() -- did not see an update to the status in the code you posted.
    if global.doorstatus == 0 then
        doorOpen()
    else
        doorClosed()
    end
end
```

I assume you are looking for the loop to run infinitely. If that is not the case you can remove the while loop and just use the code in it.